# How to process .dat file Dataframe with multiple columns in different rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to import data from .dat files.
The files have the following structure (and there are a few hundred for each measurement):

```
#-G8k5perc
#acf0
4e-07 1.67466
8e-07 1.57061
...
13.4217728 0.97419
&
#fit0
2.4e-06 1.5376
3.2e-06 1.5312
...
13.4 0.99578
&
...
#cnta0
@with g2
#cnta0
0 109.74
0.25 107.97
...
19.75 104.05
#rate0 107.2
```

I have tried:
1)

```
df = pd.read_csv("G8k5perc-1.dat")
```

which only gives one column.
Adding `,sep=' '`, `,delimiter=' '` or `,delim_whitespace=True` leads to
`ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 2`
2) 
I have seen someone using:
`from string import find, rfind, split, strip`
Which raises the error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'find' from 'string'` for all four.
3)
Creating slices and changing them afterwards wont work either:

```
acf=df[1:179]
acf["#-G8k5perc"]= acf["#-G8k5perc"].str.split(" ", n = 1, expand = True)
```

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  app.launch_new_instance()
```

Any Ideas on how to get two columns for each set of data (acf0, fit0, etc.) in the files?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use csv reader with a data format `.dat`.
Try the code below:

```
import csv

datContent = [i.strip().split() for i in open("./yourdata.dat").readlines()]

with open("./yourdata.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(datContent)
```

Then try to use pandas to make new columns:

```
import pandas as pd

def your_func(row):
    return row['x-momentum'] / row['mass']

columns_to_keep = ['#time', 'x-momentum', 'mass']
dataframe = pd.read_csv("./yourdata.csv", usecols=columns_to_keep)
dataframe['new_column'] = dataframe.apply(your_func, axis=1)

print dataframe
```

Replace `yourdata.csv` with your input file name.

Comment: vote this answer if it's the good answer or let me know of your code output for more help ! happy learning and good luck :)

Comment: The only output i get from this is:
```<_io.BufferedWriter name='G8k5perc-1.dat'>```
If i try to manipulate this object with ```acf=f[1:179]``` or something else, i get ```TypeError: '_io.BufferedWriter' object is not subscriptable```

Comment: I tried to fix your English syntax but I had to guess some words; please review.

Comment: I don't think the reader cares at all what the file is named.